# LinkedIn OAuth2.0 redirect url for iOS app without http or https

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I think this might be a very simple setting issue and since I am very new to swift and LinkedIn API I might be doing this wrong:

I am making an iOS app with swift and want to use LinkedIn to authenticate. For that, I created an application on LinkedIn Developer Network. But now I am not able to put my app redirect URL in **OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs:**

The app redirect URL in my code looks like **oauth-testapp://oauth-callback/linkedin** and its working fine with OAuth 1.0 but for OAuth 2.0 I need to have this in **http://** or **https://** format.

This is where my confusion is as I cant add my URL **oauth-testapp://oauth-callback/linkedin** in **OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs:**

[image]

I read some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281084/whats-a-redirect-uri-how-does-it-apply-to-ios-app-for-oauth2-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816529/redirecting-url-to-app-in-iphone-for-linkedin) and I don't want to create a website to redirect the user to the app or create a web view inside the app. I mean I can do it but I just want to make a POC and this is where I am blocked on. Is it at all possible without these methods? Has anyone done it with swift? Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a webview inside the app - it's not that hard and you'll need to trigger a browser anyhow - and override the behaviour for this specific (redirect URI) callback URL as described in: [Oauth 2.0 authorization for LinkedIn in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062145/oauth-2-0-authorization-for-linkedin-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For authentication in LinkedIn oauth 2.0, your redirect url should be like this: `https://com.testapp.linkedin.oauth/oauth`